# viewDidUnload alternative iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

Which method can I use to catch the event when I move to another view?
What I have tried so far and didn't work: `viewWillDisappear:`, `willMoveToParentViewController:`, `dealloc:`

I am trying to unregister an observer for notifications.

Comment: Please specify why the above solutions didn't work, especially `viewWillDisappear`. Also share some *relevant* code snippet.

Comment: Use `viewDidDisappear` or `deinit`

Comment: @Tj3n - the OP is asking about Objective-C, so should be `dealloc` rather than `deinit`

Comment: @Student - What do you mean by "didn't work"? Those methods weren't called? The observers weren't unregistered?

Comment: Please paste some relevant code that shows where and how you are registering for notifications, and where and how you are de-registering as well.

Comment: Since iOS 9 it's is no longer necessary for an `NotificationCenter` observer to un-register itself when being deallocated.

Answer (score 2):

The `viewDidUnload` method is now Deprecated.

If you want unregister an observer for notification, try in `dealloc` method:

**E.g.**

```
(void)dealloc
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
 //or
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self 
        name:@"notifiactionName" object:nil];
}
```